# Jquery UI not loading in head section, only in body asp .net web forms with master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms, master-pages

I can't make JqueryUI work if I put the library script reference in the head section, but if I put it in the body of the page works fine. Can anyone tell me why is that? Is there a way to make it work putting it in the head section?

Master Page

```
<html lang="es">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadMain" runat="server"   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
```

Content page JQueryUI doesn't work

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadMain" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/Calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/CalendarScripts/Calendar.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Same content page but JQueryUI works

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadMain" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/Calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/CalendarScripts/Calendar.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
           <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <div>
```

Comment: does it help at all if you put all the css before the js?

Comment: thanks for the answer but no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with an `asp:ScriptReference`.

I was having the same issue and, after many unsuccessful investigations, trials and errors, just now I suddenly realized that in the master page, in the `asp:ScriptManager` that is in the body tag, I had a `asp:ScriptReference` with `Name="jquery"`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
```

It came to me that maybe this `asp:ScriptReference` was conflicting with the jquery `<script src=...` tag preceding it (so, if you place them in head, they precede the `asp:ScriptManager` tag and conflict; if you place them in MainContent placeholder, they are included after the asp:ScriptManager tag and do not get messed up).

I do not have the time to investigate much further right now, but I'd like to share that removing the `<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />` allowed me to get the jquery `<script src=..."` working in head also.